# how to move index-html file in a react app bundled via vite to the public directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, vite

when i create **reactJs** vite app using the script `npm init vite app-name` the **index.html** file is located in the src file,and is putting the **index.html** file in src folder a healthy practice? if not how to move it to the public directory as it was in the react app.

Answer (score 0):

You can move index.html to any directory you want and then specify path to this category in vite.config file like so:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3001,
    open: "/public/index.html"
  }
})
```

See [the open package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open#app) for more details